# Why threads are not working properly?

Tags: java, multithreading

Here is my following code:

```
class Test {
private int x  = 0;

public void incX() {
    synchronized(this) {
       ++x;                        
    }
    System.out.println("x is: "+x+"     "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = new Test();             
    Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
        test.incX();                    
    });
    Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
        test.incX();                   
    });
    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    System.out.println("Done");
}
}
```

Here's my output:

```
x is: 2     Thread-1
x is: 1     Thread-0
```

Here thread `t2` outputs 2 but then thread `t1` should also output 2, right? As when `x` is equal to 2 then It should be visible to thread `t1`, right? So why thread `t1` is 1?

How is it possible that thread `t2` outputs 2 and then thread `t1` outputs 1? As thread `t2` already outputs 2 then the value of x should be 2. So how can thread `t1` can still output 1? Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You probably are misunderstanding.

Comment: @duffymo:  Can you explain me what I am misunderstanding?

Comment: Others have done a better job.  Nothing for me to add, except to say that when code fails to match your expectations it's best to check your assumptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with, your code is not correctly synchronized. Your expression

```
"x is: "+x+"     "+Thread.currentThread().getName()
```

reads the value of the shared variable `x` without synchronization, that is, in a data race. However, it will at least see the value as observed by the preceding `synchronized` block.

Now let's consider the possible outputs of your program. Threads proceed step by step and steps by all threads are interleaved. Consider the following sequence:

1. `Thread-0` enters `synchronized` block, reads `x == 0`, updates it to `1`, and leaves the block. The subsequent string expression reads this value of `1`.
2. `Thread-1` enters `synchronized` block, reads `x == 1`, updates it to `2`, and leaves the block. The subsequent string expression reads this value of `2`.
3. `Thread-1` enters the `synchronized` method `println` and outputs its result `2`.
4. `Thread-0` enters the `synchronized` method `println` and outputs its result `1.`

Answer (score 3):

Your entire `System.out.println` line is very far from atomic.
For example, between the construction of the string and the invocation of `System.out.println`, a lot of stuff can happen.

Let's consider an equivalent code block:

```
public void incX() {
    synchronized(this) {
       ++x;                        
    }
    String implicit = "x is: " + x + "     " + Thread.currentThread().getName();
    // <-- "Point X"
    System.out.println(implicit);
}
```

Now the scenario can go like this:

- Thread 1 starts and goes on until it reaches "Point X", having constructed a string that reads:

  > x is: 1     Thread-0
- Thread 2 starts and goes on until it reaches "Point X", having constructed a string that reads:

  > x is: 2     Thread-1
- Thread 2 invokes `System.out.println`, making the overall output so far:

  > x is: 2     Thread-1
- Thread 1 invokes `System.out.println`, making the overall output:

  > x is: 2     Thread-1
  >   x is: 1     Thread-0

Copying the value of `x` to another variable inside the `synchronized` block should be sufficient to make the behaviour meet your expectations:

```
public void incX() {
    int val;
    synchronized(this) {
       val = ++x;                        
    }
    System.out.println("x is: " + val + "     " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
```